# How does fork() work here in this C program?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    fork();
    printf("foo\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This prints "foo" 30 times. Why?

And why does it print "foo" 64 times if you pipe the output?

```
$ ./a.out | wc -l
64
```

Comment: Did you alread try?

Comment: Remember that after `fork()` two processes exist with the same values in variables. Thus, in each iteration of the loop the number of processes should duplicate. This is 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 30. I would expect 30 `foo`s output. Am I right? (Of course, I assume that none of the `fork()`s fails...)

Comment: Interesting. I get different results if I just print to terminal vs. piping it to a file or a program like less or wc -l.  I get 64 in wc -l.

Comment: Hmm, I compiled with gcc in cygwin, run, copied the output to notepad++ and got 30 lines (as expected).

Comment: @JimBaldwin If I use `./test-fork | wc -l` as you suggested I get 64 as well. This is crazy...

Comment: Yes, I think this is the real question.

Comment: @JimBaldwin If I do `./test-fork >test.txt` I can count the 64 line in notepad++ as well. Could it be that the piping changes something? (And why?)

Comment: Same thing if you pipe it to a file. `./test-fork > output.txt; wc -l output.txt`

Comment: Piping changes the output buffer from line buffered to full buffered, so fork duplicates also the buffer content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `fork()` everything gets duplicated. So you will double in each iteration. That's why it prints 2+4+8+16=30 times. This can be easily seen if you print the value of `i` together with the `PID` for the process.

As mch stated, piping changes the output buffer from line buffered to full buffered, so fork duplicates also the buffer content. That's why you get 64 printouts.